# cannot truncate the tables in landing area after transfering data

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 schemas with exactly the same 15 tables in Postgres. Data will be inserted in to first schema every 3 hours. then data needs to be transfer into second schema.
afterthat tables of the first schema needs to be truncated. (landing area needs to be empty).I wrote a trigger to transfer data after inserting to first schema into second schema.
but how tables of the first schema should be truncated?
I searched already and I tried two ways but non of them works.

1.I put the truncate command after all (insert into... conflict on... )in the same trigger's function that transfer data from first schema into second schema. which doesn't work.

2.I made another trigger which will implemented after insert into (or update) tables of second schema. which also doesn't work. why this one doesn't work? if data already inserted into second_schema. it should be possible to trucate first_schema. It isnot in use by active query.

```
Error->cannot TRUNCATE "table1" because it is being used by active queries in this session
```

what should I do? I need to tranfer data after every insert into first schema, to second schema. and then truncate all 15 tables of the first schema.
Tables of first schema should be empty for new insert.

Comment: Another option. Put the `truncate` for each table **just before** the data load.  I assume that is a script, put truncate as the first step(s) in the script.

Comment: I don't get your idea. if I truncate the tables first in the same trigger function and then use (insert into... conflict on... ), how data transfer to second schema?
if data first get truncated which data goes to second schema?

Comment: No trigger. Create a script that handles both the truncate and the re-load.

Comment: @belayer I have two schemas, first is staging area, second is reading area.
data inserted every 3 hours into staging area, I want data will transfer into reading area automatically after every insert into staging area and then truncate the staging area.
if I write a normal script it doesn't run after every insert into staging area.